# Visibility button in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a problem with visibility when the value is 0 or the highest number in an array in JavaScript

Here's my code...

```
    <!-- script fotoviewer -->
<script>

$("#fotoviewerclick").click(function(){
$("#wrapper").fadeIn(1000);
$("#lightbox").fadeIn(1000);
})

$("#lightboxbtnclose").click(function(){
$("#wrapper").fadeOut(400);
$("#lightbox").fadeOut(400);
})

$("#wrapper").click(function(){
$("#wrapper").fadeOut(400);
$("#lightbox").fadeOut(400);
})

var imagenumber = 0;
var imagenumber_count = 1;
var imagenumber_total_count = imagelist.length;
document.getElementById('counter_total').innerHTML = imagelist.length;



function btnleft(){
    var load = imagelist[imagenumber-=1];
    if (imagenumber_count > 1){imagenumber_count -= 1; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;}
    if (load) // imagenumber in array boundaries
        document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = load;
    else
        imagenumber = 0;
 }
 function btnright(){
    if (imagenumber_count < imagenumber_total_count) {
    imagenumber_count += 1;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = imagenumber_count;
  }
    var load = imagelist[imagenumber+=1];
    if (load){ // imagenumber in array boundaries
        document.getElementById('lightboxcontent').innerHTML = load;
   }
    else{
        imagenumber = imagelist.length-1;}
 }
</script>
```

When the first photo is in the viewer I don't want that the prev. button is displayed and also when I'm on the last picture, that the next button isn't desplayed

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks!!

*PS.:sorry about my bad English, I'm from Belgium*

Comment: `<script>
var imagelist=new Array(); // regular array (add an optional integer
imagelist[0]="<img src='http://cdniphone.i-culture.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Apple-Store-Amsterdam-iPhoneclub.nl_.jpg' width='450px'/>";       // argument to control array's size)
imagelist[1]="<img src='/uploads/2/foto-2.JPG' width='450px'/>";
imagelist[2]="<img src='/uploads/2/foto-3.JPG' width='450px'/>";
</script>` this is the array, this and the code above are between the body tags

Comment: edit the question and add to it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic logic is

if your imagenumber_count reaches 0 then visibility:hidden for the left button, else visibility:visible

if your imagenumber_count is the same as the total image count then right button visibility:hidden, else visibility:visible